Releases File Health result one error in xenforo 2.3
File Health result one error. I am posting a problem
src/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/NOTICE.txt. Problem in txt file.
How can i solve the problem. Anyone please, help me.
I am trying to rid out of the problem related to file health check.

link bold  src/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/NOTICE.txt

Please edit the original question to include the relevant text as a text-block. If there is relevant code for a simple reproducible test case, please include that too. Text and code blocks should be delimited by triple-back-ticks. We CANNOT access the NOTICE.TXT for which you posted a link.
